# Fetching api and passing up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I keep struggling to understand this, and just am not getting it.

I want to fetch data from an API, and display it in the nativescript playground on iOS.

```
function getEvent() {
        var event6 = "stringy event";
        var myObj2 = {
          name: 'Ed',
          favoriteFood: 'pie'
    };
        var event8;
        var event9 = new Object;
        console.log("-----httpmodule ----------------------------");
        httpModule.getJSON("https://agile-brushlands-36817.herokuapp.com/events/4.json").then(function(result) {
          console.log("event api fetched: " + JSON.stringify(result));
          event8 = JSON.stringify(result);
          console.log("event8:" + event8);
          event9 = parse(event8);
          console.log("event9: ");
          }, function(error) {
             console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
        console.log("---leave getEvent------------------------------");
        return event9;

    }`
```

It nicely logs the "event api fetched" and the data I wanted. But nothing I try will get data out of the function.

I can access event6 and myObj2 nicely outside the function. But nothing dealing with the api data. I've tried "then" everywhere, but still am not understanding the mechanism.

(And why doesn't console.log("event9: "); log this simple string?)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it has nothing to do with NativeScript, it's all about `Promise` in JavaScript. It's asynchronous, so you can't return the value directly. It will be something like,

```
function getEvent() {
    var event6 = "stringy event";
    var myObj2 = {
        name: 'Ed',
        favoriteFood: 'pie'
    };
    var event8, event9;
    console.log("-----httpmodule ----------------------------");
    return httpModule.getJSON("https://agile-brushlands-36817.herokuapp.com/events/4.json")
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log("event api fetched: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            event8 = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log("event8:" + event8);
            event9 = parse(event8);
            console.log("event9: " + event9);
            console.log("---leave getEvent------------------------------");
            return event9;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}

getEvent()
    .then(function (event9) {
        // event9 may be undefined, if there was an error while fetching
        console.log(event9);
    });
```

Learn more about [Promise here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I've seen so many approaches to this, it's just amazing. Do you know why, in my code, "console.log("event api fetched: " + JSON.stringify(result));" echoes my data nicely, but the line after it,  console.log("event9: "); (e.g. log a string tag) doesn't?

Comment: Ah. Can only reference result once. Removing the log api fetched line & fixing the parse logs as  "'event9: [object Object]'"